# How do I get rid of a tooltip using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have tried the following code to remove the alt tag tool tip from anchor. Here is the [site](http://rmjoy.com/portfolio-item/city-farmer/) The images in the portfolio I am trying to remove the tooltip from using jquery because its a purchased theme a friend is using and I cant figure out where to get rid of the alt tag in the wordpress code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     $('.loader').click(function(e) { 
         e.preventDefault(); 
         $('.loader').removeAttr('alt');
      });

});
```

Comment: "alt" is not the tooltip. That is the "title" attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip shows up because of the `title` attribute, not `alt`.

```
$('.loader').removeAttr('title');
```